# How do I escape special characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
select * from tablename where fields like "%string "hi"  %";
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hi" "' at line 1

How do I build this query?

Comment: This may be dupe hammered into *[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174)*... (I am not saying it should or is correct to do  - just what may happen.)

Answer (score 134):

> ***The information provided in this answer can lead to insecure programming practices.***
>
> The information provided here depends highly on MySQL configuration, including (but not limited to) the program version, the database client and character-encoding used.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

```
MySQL recognizes the following escape sequences.
\0     An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.
\'     A single quote (“'”) character.
\"     A double quote (“"”) character.
\b     A backspace character.
\n     A newline (linefeed) character.
\r     A carriage return character.
\t     A tab character.
\Z     ASCII 26 (Control-Z). See note following the table.
\\     A backslash (“\”) character.
\%     A “%” character. See note following the table.
\_     A “_” character. See note following the table.
```

So you need

```
select * from tablename where fields like "%string \"hi\" %";
```

Although as [Bill Karwin notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql/881252#881252), using double quotes for string delimiters isn't standard SQL, so it's good practice to use single quotes. This simplifies things:

```
select * from tablename where fields like '%string "hi" %';
```

Comment: Why is it insecure to escape a character?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Because you can't rely on it entirely to sanitize untrusted input. That relies on you escaping everything the server interprets differently, and as the remark says, depends on configuration, versions and encodings used. A new version can easily introduce something new that you didn't consider, or you may easily forget some characters or attackers can find some edge cases. Finally, escapng drives you away from the good practice: use parameters for everything untrusted, which are guarranted to work as expected by the DB engine.

Comment: @Alejandro use parameters for everything untrusted is bad for human to debug sql.And you can not put a sql with parameters into command line tool mysql. So I have to escape all character correct.

Comment: @bronzeman If your debug tools don't handle parameters correctly they can certainly get in the way, but that's only during debug, not in a real program. Command line isn't a serious client to use in programs (at the very least, just because it doesn't support parameters), but most likely is used  in adhoc queries mostly in administrative contexts, not directly subject to untrusted user input.

Comment: @Alejandro you can not use parameters for everything untrusted for mysql. The database name,field name, table name, limit number can not use parameters.

Answer (score 39):

I've developed my own MySQL escape method in Java (if useful for anyone).

See class code below.

Warning: wrong if NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES SQL mode is enabled.

```java
private static final HashMap<String,String> sqlTokens;
private static Pattern sqlTokenPattern;

static
{           
    //MySQL escape sequences: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-syntax.html
    String[][] search_regex_replacement = new String[][]
    {
                //search string     search regex        sql replacement regex
            {   "\u0000"    ,       "\\x00"     ,       "\\\\0"     },
            {   "'"         ,       "'"         ,       "\\\\'"     },
            {   "\""        ,       "\""        ,       "\\\\\""    },
            {   "\b"        ,       "\\x08"     ,       "\\\\b"     },
            {   "\n"        ,       "\\n"       ,       "\\\\n"     },
            {   "\r"        ,       "\\r"       ,       "\\\\r"     },
            {   "\t"        ,       "\\t"       ,       "\\\\t"     },
            {   "\u001A"    ,       "\\x1A"     ,       "\\\\Z"     },
            {   "\\"        ,       "\\\\"      ,       "\\\\\\\\"  }
    };

    sqlTokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String patternStr = "";
    for (String[] srr : search_regex_replacement)
    {
        sqlTokens.put(srr[0], srr[2]);
        patternStr += (patternStr.isEmpty() ? "" : "|") + srr[1];            
    }
    sqlTokenPattern = Pattern.compile('(' + patternStr + ')');
}


public static String escape(String s)
{
    Matcher matcher = sqlTokenPattern.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, sqlTokens.get(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Used your search replace table in a mysql procedure where I need to escape a tab delimiter to be correctly inserted in the db like '\t'. thx

Comment: Do you have C# version?

Answer (score 27):

You should use single-quotes for string delimiters.  The single-quote is the standard SQL string delimiter, and double-quotes are identifier delimiters (so you can use special words or characters in the names of tables or columns).

In MySQL, double-quotes work (nonstandardly) as a string delimiter by default (unless you set `ANSI` SQL mode).  If you ever use another brand of SQL database, you'll benefit from getting into the habit of using quotes standardly.

Another handy benefit of using single-quotes is that the literal double-quote characters within your string don't need to be escaped:

```
select * from tablename where fields like '%string "hi" %';
```

Comment: I concur with the single-quote idea because if you switch to, say, PostgresSQL it will stubbornly refuse your queries and you must use single quotes.  It is a good practice.

Comment: That handles the example, but what about the more general case? E.g. for a backslash, `\\`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Use a double-backslash to get one literal backslash character. This is the same it is in virtually every programming language. See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 18):

MySQL has the string function [QUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_quote), and it should solve the problem

Comment: Except it doesn't quote `LIKE`'s `%` character, so it is pretty useless

Comment: Also pay attention, that `QUOTE` adds surrounding single qoutes for string values

Answer (score 9):

For strings like that, for me the most comfortable way to do it is doubling the ' or ", as explained in the MySQL manual:

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> ```
> A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.
>
> A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.
>
> Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).
>
> A “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a
> ```
>
> Strings quoted with “'” need no special treatment.

It is from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not escape `%` and `_`, so you should escape MySQL wildcards  (`%` and `_`) separately.

Comment: [Function *mysql_real_escape_string()* was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and was removed in PHP 7.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: You could only use this if you are using PHP. For any other application, this answer is pretty useless

Answer (score 1):

For testing how to insert the double quotes in MySQL using the terminal, you can use the following way:

> TableName(Name,DString) - > Schema
>   insert into TableName values("Name","My QQDoubleQuotedStringQQ")

After inserting the value you can update the value in the database with double quotes or single quotes:

```
update table TableName replace(Dstring, "QQ", "\"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a variable when searching in a string, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is good for you. Just my suggestion:

```
$char = "and way's 'hihi'";
$myvar = mysql_real_escape_string($char);

select * from tablename where fields like "%string $myvar  %";
```

Comment: This function is depreciated in PHP 5.5 and removed from 7.0