# Storing data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, special-characters, storing-data

I want to store some values like **"st paul's school"** in mysql database. However due to the special symbol    **'**  I am unable to store such values in mysql. I tried varchar datatype but it doesn't work. Please suggest a suitable method or datatype to store **'** in mysql.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to search for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-value-in-mysql-containg-single-quotes

Answer (score 4):

Add two single quotes like this '' or escape it like this \'

Comment: But Iam fetching these names from a website. so I never know the position of single quote in the names. so i cant add double quote at the position of single quote.

Comment: How are you inserting these names into the database ? If you are updating via a application (C#, Java e.t.c) Can you not use a string replace function to replace instances of single quotes with two single quotes ?

Comment: The name can also be st mary's school in place of st paul's school. for using replace function, I need to check every character of every name. indirectly it will affect performance of my code. Can you suggest me a suitable datatype for storing values with apostrof in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it directly on MySQL Server, *double the single quote* and it will work. Example

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('St. Paul''s School')
```

But on front-end, use *PreparedStatements* for this.

If you are using `PHP`, use `PDO` or `MySQLI` extension on this to avoid `SQL Injection`. Please see thearticle below,

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: But Iam fetching these names from a website. so I never know the position of single quote in the names. so i cant add double quote at the position of single quote.

Comment: what programming are you using? `PHP`?

Answer (score 0):

If u have variable with this apostrof use `htmlentities`

```
 $your_var = "St. Paul's School";
 $your_var = htmlentities($your_var);
 INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ('$your_var')
```

If u have just string u can do double quotes like that

```
 INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ("St. Paul's School")
```

Comment: if u fetch it from other variables , here the first solution for u

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the quote sign with it's entity.
If you are using **php**

```
<?php
    $str = "st paul's school";
    $str = str_replace("\'","&acute;",$str);
    $str = str_replace("\"","&quot;",$str);
?>
```

You can also use

```
$str= htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_real_escape_string($text) to escape those ' in the text you are inserting to the database.