# quotation marks in PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble putting together mySQL queries containing quotation marks when I have to put them through PHP statements that also use quotation marks, and this gets even messier when I add PHP variables. So far, the best I've come up with is something like this:

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT document FROM `mentioned_places` WHERE name="'.$mentionedPlace.'";';
```

Which is really just a quagmire of quotation marks. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Use prepared statements (mysqli/pdo) and you will be relieved from this mess :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php   http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Also, you can just use a variable directly in a double quoted string: `$a = "Hello $world";`

Answer (score 2):

Escape everything. If you are using `mysql_` statements, stop using them as they are deprecated. Take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Both of them escape symbols if you prepare the queries, so you also prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

To secure your application you should use prepared statements with [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Then you can separate your variables from your query and bind them to the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)**:

```php
$sqlQuery = "SELECT document FROM `mentioned_places` WHERE name='$mentionedPlace'";
```

**But you're better off to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) either with mysqli or PDO.**

Using mysqli:

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
$sql = "SELECT document FROM `mentioned_places` WHERE name = ?";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param("s", $mentionedPlace);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($document);
$documents = array();
while ($query->fetch()) {
    $documents[] = $document;
}
$db->close();
```

Using PDO:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=UTF8', 'user', 'userpwd');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $sql = "SELECT document FROM `mentioned_places` WHERE name = ?";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($mentionedPlace));
    $documents = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Exeption: " .$e->getMessage(); //TODO better error handling
}
$query = null;
$db = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this procedure for give quotation for MYSQL query

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-a-value-containg-single-quotes-in-mysql) and 
2.[links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Its more useful.
Better you can use [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php%20php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)