# Insert Strings that contain " ` " or " ' " to the database table - Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, sql-insert

I have to insert some strings to my database.

The problem is that every time I use " ` " or " ' " it causes errors in the Sql.

For ex, when someone types "that's great" , it just messes everything up.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a value containg single quotes in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-a-value-containg-single-quotes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the real escape string function. Actually, MySQL prevents ' or ` from entering the system in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Function Syntax: `mysql_real_escape_string($your_string)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the mysqli escape string function:https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php (you shouldn't be using the mysql functions as they are depreciated) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Could you please help me upgrading my code to mysqli? lets get into a chat.

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared/parameterized query.

Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php