# MySQL: fix data inserted inside quotes in DB

Tags: mysql

I need to fix some (bad) inserted data in DB, I had data inserted with single qoutes like: ('love')

I want to move this to (love), without effect on something like (we're),

info table (structure)

```
id     text
1     'love'
2     'man'
3     we're..
4     John
5     'Sarah'
```

I want to fix "info" table to be:

info table (structure)

```
id     text
1      love
2      man
3      we're..
4      John
5      Sarah
```

I can select this data using:

```
select * from info where text like "'%'"
```

thanks,

Comment: want to remove single quotes, if data inserted inside it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a value containg single quotes in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-a-value-containg-single-quotes-in-mysql)

Comment: @ChristianMark I need to fix already inserted data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this untested query:

`update info set text = replace(text,"'","") where text like "'%'"`

Comment: Even this is working on MySQL, don't use `"` for string. It will fail on every other, standard compatible system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement to update all the rows of the table.

```
update Table_Name
set ColumnName= REPLACE(ColumnName,'''','')
where ColumnName LIKE ('''%''')
```