# To insert a single quotes in a table using query

Tags: mysql

I want to insert single quotes with the data in which I am trying to insert it in a mysql table
Example    id    column
           1     data='rose'

data='rose' should be saved under column
 My Actual query is UPDATE test SET ItemType ='doctype="\'text'\"'WHERE ITEMINDEX='221'

Comment: If the column has type of `char/varchar/text` etc. there is no reason to unsave quotes. You do something wrong, didn't show us code.

Comment: I used update table set column='data='\rose'\' where id=1 but it is not working

Comment: you should elaborate your question by an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a value containg single quotes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036/insert-a-value-containg-single-quotes-in-mysql)

Comment: @Dhivya: try to find how to escape quotes in SQL. It's easy.

Comment: @panther I used escaping character but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.The following code solved my issue
UPDATE test SET ItemType ='doctype=''text''' WHERE ITEMINDEX='221'