# MySQL SELECT * WHERE name = "something with a backslash \"

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
table_id | name   | amount
1        | Arby\'s| 12
2        | Wendy's| 8
```

I usually do a

SELECT * WHERE table_id = whatever

But I would like (instead) do:

SELECT * WHERE name = "Arby\'s";

However, I seem to be running into problems with the backslash. The result isn't showing up at all. I've also tried

```
SELECT * WHERE name = 'Arby's;
```

Without any luck.

Is there any way to search by name if the name contains apostrophes or other special characters (ampersands etc?)

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE name = 'Arby\'s';` - you're missing a closing `'`

Comment: Sorry that was more of a typo in my question...just edited it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have the backslash in your data to begin with.

Comment: By that, do you mean I should stripslashes before I do an insert? I'm using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on PHP, you can use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

You might also want to look at this
[How do I escape special characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql)

Comment: ["`Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. `"](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'Arby\\\'s'
```

Escape the backslash with a backslash and escape the apostrophe with another backslash leads to 3 backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * WHERE name = 'Arby\'s';
```

You're missing a closing `'` on the end of your string. That will match `Arby's`. If you wanted to match `Arby\'s` (which I don't think you do) it would be:

```
 SELECT * WHERE name = 'Arby\\\'s';
```

Back slashes need to be 'double escaped', as it were, because they are the escape character. So to match `\\` your query needs to be `\\\\`. When they immediately precede another character that needs to be escaped, you end up with another one - so to match `\\'` you need `\\\\\'`

I suggest you [read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html).

Comment: Well, he has the backslash in his sample data, so I guess he wants to match that, too.

Comment: I know it's confusing, but I interpret that as an attempt at escaping the single quote but leaving off the string-closing quote.