# Find double quotes in MySQL column

Tags: mysql

I want to find data with double quotes. I have the next simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE "%\"%";
```

But I have syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"%\"%' at line 1
```

What should I do to find this data with double quotes(")?

Comment: use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the \ character is used by the LIKE operator itself you have to double it when you use it to escape another character like the double quote.

[see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE "%\\"%";
```

should work for you.

as will changing out the double quotes for single quotes to enclose the literal

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%"%';
```

as you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633749/358858)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%"%';
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%\"%'; this one is work.Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have found the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%"%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If in database fields has both single and double quotes then in query follow below syntex:

```
"select id,name 
from table_name 
where 
Replace(
Replace(name, \"'\", '`' ),'\"','`')='".value."'
```