# Regexp pattern match in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in which I am taking user data and saving it in JSON format. On starting I forgot to check for double quotes now I am getting issue on json_decode while taking data back for db. For example my data is like

```
{"key1"=>"this is a sample" code","key2"=>"this is a sample code""}
```

I tried below:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%"%';
```

But it gives me all data but I need only data which has double quotes in between.

Comment: Does `key1` and `key2` are always the same?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question [and the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633757/5517065).  The short answer is that you need to escape the quote twice: `SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%\\"%'`

Comment: Your query should work. Have you verified that the other names do not have double quotes in them?