# SQL Exception (unrecognized token) when string contains quotes

Tags: android, mysql, sqlexception

I'm getting SQL Exception (unrecognized token) when I use my function to retrieve data from "mysql.db". The exception occurs when String **address** has quotes inside.

I already tried to change this line

```
KEY_ADDRESS + "='" + address + "'",
```

to

```
KEY_ADDRESS + "=\"" + address + "\"",
```

It solves my problem for strings containing single quote (') and (`), but creates another problem for strings containing double quotes (").

I tried using

```
DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(address);
```

with no effect.

I tried to use *escape* function from this question: [How do I escape special characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql), but it did not work.

This is my code:

```
public Cursor getNameFromAddress(String address) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRINC, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NAME,
                    KEY_ADDRESS
                    },
                    KEY_ADDRESS + "='" + address + "'",
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: `sqlEscapeString` seems like the right way to do this. What do you mean "no effect"? What does that method return?

Comment: I'm sorry, when I use sqlEscapeString the returned result is 'uvuwub}f84xuy}bap}zu84uvw84"\`w'         and the SQLiteException says: near "uvuwub": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, address FROM sqltable WHERE address="uvuwub}f84xuy}bap}zu84uvw84"`w"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those `selectionArgs` / `whereArgs` are intended to be used for that:

```
Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRINC, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME,
                KEY_ADDRESS
                },
                KEY_ADDRESS + "=?",
                new String[] { address },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

replace all `"='" + stuff + "'"` with `"=?"` and put the data to fill the `?`s in the order they have to be filled in a `String[]`

`?` will then automatically be replaced by escaped String data.

Answer (score 2):

missing "?" symbol

```
Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PRINC, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME,
                KEY_ADDRESS
                },
                KEY_ADDRESS + "=?" ,
                new String[]{address},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
queryText = "select * from yourtable where address = ?";
mDb.rawQuery(queryText, new String[] {addressValue});
```

This way you solve your problem and also defend your system against SQL Injection.