# MySql concat and quotes

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<td>style="background:url('myimage.jpg') no-repeat;"> + column + </td>
```

But I get a MySQL error when trying:

```
Concat ('<td>style="background:url('myimage.jpg') no-repeat;">', info_text, '</td') as Nicetext
```

I suppose it is all the quotes that mess things up.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: See this article on escaping characters: <br>
<a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql</a>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your strings include quote marks. You will have to escape them. Try something like:

```
Concat ('<td>style="background:url(\'myimage.jpg\') no-repeat;">', info_text, '</td') as Nicetext
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't escaped the quotes. Try this :

```
Concat ('<td>style="background:url(\'myimage.jpg\') no-repeat;">', info_text, '</td') as Nicetext
```