# MYSQL WHERE LIKE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am attempting to use the LIKE clause in a mysql statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1956%'
```

The data matched data within the 'FilePath' Column is:

```
C:\SCAN\Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1830\TEST
```

The above SQL statement works fine and picks up the relevent row, but if I for example add the "\" character into the end of the LIKE clause (like follows) it does not pick up the row correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1956\%'
```

Funnily enough though if I place a '\' character at the beginning of LIKE clause (like follows) it picks up the row perfectly fine - this has me baffled.

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%\Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1956%'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Within LIKE, `_` is a wildcard matching a single character and so that needs escaping to correctly match a literal '_' instead of potentially matching anything.  Additionally you are mentioning trying to match a string ending in 1830 with a like ending 1956. Finally as mentioned by J W and the MySQL documentation you need to escape backslashes twice

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM batches 
WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker\_Apple\_Ben\_20-10-1830\\\\%'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ce74/3

Answer (score 3):

adding `\` in the current query escapes `%`, try this

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker\_Apple\_Ben\_20-10-1956\\\\%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68003/2)

> To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Answer (score 2):

Use quadruple escape:

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1956\\\\%'
```

[Explanation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your '\' character. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE FilePath LIKE '%Parker_Apple_Ben_20-10-1956\\%'
```

Comment: Hi, I did try that before but no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is because `\%` is an escape character in MySQL, for more information, see the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/881208/1666167

Answer (score 0):

You should escape special characters like \, ', _ etc in mysql like `\\` , `\'`, `\_`