# which characters should be escaped when use php with database

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm have a simple HTML form, in which are there some input fields and textareas. Users are allowed to input any texts they want.

In my backend, I use PHP to insert these data into the database (in my case, PostgreSQL). However, I found some special characters, such as **single quote, double quote**, may lead to failures for SQL execution. I think **backslash** with other possible character may result in the same problem.

So can anyone list all these special characters I should be care of, or even better, can anyone suggest some simple but reliable methods to avoid such problem ?

Comment: If you do the database interaction right, there are no problems with such strings. How do you interact with your database? Are you trying to create SQL by hand?

Comment: Nothing should be escaped. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @hakre - It's getting so many duplicates that even Stack Overflow search engine can find it :)

Comment: May be this could help you [how to escape special character in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql)

Comment: @KishorSubedi — Since the question states that the database isn't MySQL, not so much.

Comment: @Ensom - The question is not bad but we cannot type again the awesome answers it already has. I've removed the `html` tag because it doesn't need special handling. In SQL context, it's just *text*.

Comment: @hakre yes I am just using plain SQL statement in my php code? any better ways to do it ?

Comment: Yes, use prepared statements. You are using PostgreSQL anyway, you should adopt from the good practices it offers. It's a very fine database, be proud of it :) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+prepared+statements+Postgres - Upvote questions and answers that help you along the way.