# How do I escape the "&" symbol in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, xp-cmdshell

I have to execute the following code in query editor

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'sqlps -command "$http=New-Object system.Net.WebClient;$http.uploadString(\"http://192.168.2.3:8080/ThermalMap/DBTest.jsp\",\"param1=somevalue & param2=thriu\")"'
```

It gives me error.

But the following code is working well and gives me output

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'sqlps -command "$http=New-Object system.Net.WebClient;$http.uploadString(\"http://192.168.2.3:8080/ThermalMap/DBTest.jsp\",\"param1=somevalue\")"'
```

Here in second code am passing single parameter and I don't get any error If I pass two parameter I need to add "&" symbol and am getting error. How can I escape "&" symbol here?

Comment: Please refer to the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql

Comment: @jean-paul: the question you refer to is for MySql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175398%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) you need to escape ampersands like this: `^&`. Unescaped ampersands are treated as a command separators.