# Mysql Like containing wildcart giving unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

I have a varchar column inside a very simple MySQL Database table that contains 2 different types of product references :

one like : 14521_451_288, and the others like 45742154

to be able to manage them, I'm using the following code :

```
WHERE ref LIKE '%_%'
```

But all the results are returned, even the references without underscore. Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: _ stand for any one character in a LIKE expression. That's why you return all values. You need to escape the _ character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_ stand for any one character in a LIKE expression. That's why you return all values. You need to escape the _ character.

Try this:

```
WHERE ref LIKE '%\_%';
```

**References**:

[String Literals on MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
where ref <> instr('_') > 0
```

because `_` stands for any **single** character in the `like` expression while `%` stands for any character**s** in the expression.