# I need help in special characters to my phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html

Am try to insert strings containing special characters like single quote and double quote (',") but it's refusing to insert or  even when it does and I want to display it in HTML it shows codes instead the character I typed.

For instance I have a form when i type things with single quotation mark like this These are an example's of them because of the single quote it does not insert it into myphpadmin and if I display them it shows characters like this `&#13;&#10;&#13` please someone should me correct these two mistakes

Comment: You should try and escape your characters! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Is this pasted content from MS word?  It may be that they are the smart quotes or curly quotes instead of the normal quotes  If so I use this function to clean them

```
( normal quotes are &#39; single &#34; double ).

function convert_smart_quotes($text){
        $search = array(
            "\xe2\x80\x98", // "'"
            "\xe2\x80\x99", // "'"
            "\xe2\x80\x9c", // '"'
            "\xe2\x80\x9d", // '"'
            "\xe2\x80\x93", // '-'
            "\xe2\x80\x94", // '-'
            "\xe2\x80\xa6", // '...'
            chr(145),
            chr(146),
            chr(147),
            chr(148),
            chr(150),
            chr(151),
            chr(133)    
        );

        $replace = array(
            "'",
            "'",
            '"',
            '"',
            '-',
            '-',
            '...',
            "'",
            "'",
            '"',
            '"',
            '-',
            '-',
            '...'
        );

        $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);

        return $text;
    }
```

p.s. the OP would most likely have a syntax error in his query if they where normal quotes and not escaped properly.