# escape special characters in database select query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have the following query which does not work in case that the name contain special characters:

```
 case 'byMovie':

  $items_per_page = 20;
  $offset = 0;
  $page_count = 0;

  include('Connection.php');
  $query1 = $conn->prepare("
SELECT DISTINCT s.starName
              , s.starImdbID
              , s.movieName
              , p.posterLink 
           FROM star_film as s 
           LEFT 
           JOIN star_Posters as p 
             ON s.starImdbID = p.starImdbID  
          WHERE s.movieName LIKE :q
");
  $query1->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'));
  $row_count = $query1->rowCount();
  $page_count = (int)ceil($row_count / $items_per_page);
  $page = min($page_count, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
           'options' => array(
           'default'   => 1,
           'min_range' => 1,
          ),
      )));
       if($page > $page_count) { //double check that request page is in range
           $page = 1;     // error to user, maybe set page to 1
       }

   $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page;
   $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT s.starName, s.starImdbID, s.movieName, p.posterLink FROM star_film as s LEFT JOIN star_Posters as p ON s.starImdbID = p.starImdbID  WHERE s.movieName LIKE :q LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page);
   $query->execute(array(':q' => '%' . $searchText . '%'));

break;
}
```

for example if the movie name is 'a fish story' it shows me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20,20' at line
>   1' in /var/www/searchcast.php:90 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/searchcast.php(90): PDO->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT...') #1
>   {main} thrown in /var/www/searchcast.php on line 90

I tried with adding mysql_real_escape_string(s.movieName) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql), but it didn't work too.

Could someone kindly help me?

Thanks

Comment: I find that closing parenthesis confusing.

Comment: @Strawberry: sorry, i just edited my question

Comment: `'-20,20' ` is the $offset really -20?

Comment: @mihai: even without offset art when I write query directly in DB, again I receive the same error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a fish story'' "

Comment: CAn you edit your question with your query and/or the values in those variables?

Comment: @Mihai: I just edited my question :)

Comment: Right before  $offset = ($page - 1) * $items_per_page; echo out you $page variable

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be **nonnegative** integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

I think the error is related to `offset` value you're using (apparently `-20`). You have to figure out a way to avoid that number to be negative.

Seeing your code, it becomes negative when `$page = 0` which translates in:

```
$offset = (0 - 1) * 20 = -20;
```

and hence the error. You could force the value of `$page` to be one when it's 0 or something like that.

Hope it helps.