# How to query an array of data that has a Single quote?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

I have a problem in my query. I retrieve the data using sqlsrv_query to move the data from Microsoft SQL 2008 to my mySQL server. The result of my query below:

[image]

I want to save the data in my MYSQL without any error in apostrophe. I tried to execute print_r() function but it does not work. I want to show them through foreach but it does not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: print_r() doesn't save data to a database; String data should be escaped before storing to a database to prevent quotes from breaking the SQL query.... or you should be using bind variables with your SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

Escape it as follows

```
public 'sample' => string 'SHAKEY\'S0002' (length=12)
```

Refer to this entry for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql)