# Replacing text with a wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, wildcard

I need every instance of `<tag%/tag>` inside of a column to be replaced with nothing (`''` or deleted). The content inside of the tag varies. How do I do this while keeping the text that surrounds it?

For example: `CONTENT <tag>various stuff</tag> CONTENT`. I want to keep all content but remove the tags and everything inside of them, resulting in `CONTENT CONTENT`.

Edit: What? This has nothing to do with special characters.

I've worked around my problem by just exporting the table, opening it in a text editor, search+replacing and importing. I'm still unaware of any way to do this in SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to escape special character in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) for a link to a possible solution (installing a UDF.)

Comment: Haha that's ridiculous but thanks for clearing it up!