# Mysql query quote syntax error NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a value: `something's`. Value also can be `a's'a` etc. Sometimes value is `something | a` and so on. It works fine. Trying to insert it in mysql:

```
mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO `something` (`users`,`other`) VALUES (\'' + value + '\',\'' + other + '\')'
```

It returns syntax error. How can I insert that value with `'` symbol in mysql.query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating query with values is really bad idea, basically you need just to escape your values properly, but for better security you should look for example on this [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#preparing-queries)
 lib with prepared statements, and read something about SQL Injections.

Also related: [Preventing SQL injection in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778572/preventing-sql-injection-in-node-js)

Comment: That value is not from user, so there is no difference.

Comment: @ArnasA. Ok, if you know set of such possible characters - just escape it with a backslash like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/881208/1030820).
Or if you don't know set of possible characters - use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) for this

Comment: Can you explain more? Is this right? mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO something (users,other) VALUES (\'' + mysqlConnection.escape(value) + '\',\'' + other + '\')'

Comment: `mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO tableName (users, other) VALUES (" + value + "," + other + ")")`

But values by themselves must be escaped, e.g. each occurrence of `'` symbol inside values should be transformed to `\'`, you may write additional function for this, or use it from another special lib.