# MySQL: Inverted comma -> ( ' ) and double quotation -> ( " ) errors in insertion query

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, fxml, netbeans-8

I am trying to make a to-do list using NetBeans-8.0.2 and JavaFX (FXMLApplication) that stores memory into MySQL database.

I know that, SQL query takes inverted comma -> ( ' ) and 
double quotation -> ( " ) as the same to understand a string.

Now, what i am trying is, (today is my sister's birthday) i am trying to add a task in my list that says: *It's Rahi's birthday!*

but, due to sql query, it is failing.

it's because inside the code, input's inverted comma is making a complexity in the sql query as a whole.

```
 @FXML
private void handleAddTaskAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String date = addTaskDatePicker.getValue().toString();
    System.out.println(date);
    String hour = hourComboBox.getValue() + "";
    String minute = minuteComboBox.getValue() + "";

    String where = whereField.getText();

    String header = headerField.getText();
    String description = descriptionArea.getText();

    if(hour.length()==0)
        hour= "12 AM";
    if(minute.length()==0)
        minute= "00";
    if(header.length()==0)
        header= "(No header available)";
    if(description.length()==0)
        description= "(No description available)";
    if(header.length()==0 && description.length()==0){
        header= "(Empty task)";
        description= "(Empty description)";
    }

    String query = "insert into task values('" + date + "','" + hour + " " + minute + " minutes', '"
            + header + "', '" + description + "', 'at " + where + "');";

    if (date.length() >= 1) {
        try {
            statement.execute(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText("Error occured!");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setHeaderText("You must select a date.");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

i want to store the message as it is typed. Any solutions ?

my database table description and The GUI are attached as picture.
Ask me if you need anything else.
Thank you.

Picture of: [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhYda.png) and 
Picture of: [Table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiUh1.png)

Comment: Use an escape character, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-to-escape-special-character-in-mysql

Comment: _SQL query takes inverted comma -> ( ' ) and double quotation -> ( " ) as the same to understand a string._ No, single quotes and double quotes have different meaning. Single quotes are for data strings, and double quotes are for names in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to inject your values, it will escape them for you.

Comment: Yes.  And a `PreparedStatement` will take care of all manner of quoting / escaping issues that you never anticipated.  Pasting SQL queries together manually from user input is just begging for an SQL injection attack.  But a code example would be nice to round out this answer.