# Avoid symbolic error in MySql when user selected options transmitted

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have VB.net website. Somewhere I have used Update Query which has no errors in terms of syntax but suppose If user has selected some symbolic values like below

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = ''A'-wing' Where ID = '123'
```

So here in column the value 'A'-wing has quote which result to syntax error in my query. How do I avoid users option related error in query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape special characters in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your quotes by adding a backslash in front of them. Change your query to this:

```
UPDATE Table SET Column = '\'A\'-wing' Where ID = '123'
```

For more informations about this, check the official documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: Query I am not parsing manually. User selects the values & if such symbol occurred in selection then only error comes.

Comment: I don't get what's the problem. Can't you add a check if the table name contains quotes and escape them?