# Escape string within %

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I use PyMySQL to query from a MySQL database in python:

```
filter = "Pe"
connection = pymysql.connect(host="X", user="X", password="X", db="X", port=3306, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name LIKE '%%s%'"
cursor.execute(sql, (filter))
response = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

This returns nothing.
I could write:

```
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name LIKE '%" + filter +"%'"
```

and execute: `cursor.execute(sql)`, but then I lose the escaping, which makes the program vulnerable for injection attacks, right?

Is there way I could insert the value into the LIKE without losing the escape?

`...WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%'"` does not work. I think %s adds ' on both sides of the replaced escaped string as a part of its function within PyMySQL.

Comment: You have to escape the special char %. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/881208/6635287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the whole pattern as a query parameter, and use a ***tuple***:

```
filter = "%Pe%"
sql = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name LIKE %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (filter,))
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not think of that. Solved it.

Comment: What if there is another replacement in that line? "%(key)s id='%s'" % {'key': 'value'}

Answer (score 0):

Double the `%` you want to keep.

```
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%'"
```

Comment: Does not work. I think %s adds ' on both sides of the replaced escaped string as a part of its function within PyMySQL.