# How to get SELECT to output escaped "\0" character

Tags: mysql, perl, character-encoding, escaping, ascii

When I run query #1:

```
SELECT * FROM $TABLE INTO OUTFILE $FILE CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\\\' TERMINATED BY '|';
```

There is this one field value that is outputted as:

```
blah\0
```

I am trying to get identical output without using `INTO OUTFILE`.

query #2 with Perl code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");
$query->execute;
open(FILE_OUT, ">$FILE");
```

However, the same column above is outputted as

```
blah
```

So the `\0` character (ASCII NUL) is outputted differently.  How do I modify query #2 to output `blah\0`?

The modification could be in either MySQL query or Perl.  The column's Collation is utf8_general_ci.  I've tried using `CONVERT($column using utf8)` but that still displayed `blah`, and I'm not sure how I would apply it to every column of every table when outputting.

Update:

This Perl code worked in escaping the NUL character.

```
$row =~ s/\0/\\0/g;
```

But there are many other MySQL special characters, is there a way to escape them all at once instead of handling them one by one?

Comment: You'll find a lot of related info in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql).  To print NUL you can use [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). See tutorial [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html).  Finally, you can always double backslashes with a regex for the whole string but that may not cut it.

Answer (score 1):

The [quote method](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#quote) of the database handle should be able to quote any special characters:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select '\0'");

$sth->execute;
while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
        my ($col) = @$row;
        print "[$col] is quoted as ", $dbh->quote($col), "\n";
}
```

On my version of MySQL this prints:

```
[] is quoted as '\0'
```

If I pipe that through `hexdump -C` we get

```
00000000  5b 00 5d 20 69 73 20 71  75 6f 74 65 64 20 61 73  |[.] is quoted as|
00000010  20 27 5c 30 27 0a                                 | '\0'.|
00000016
```