# How do i escape both backslash and double quotes in a single query while export MySQL outfile csv

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-csv

```
SELECT `col 1`, `col 2`, `col 3`, `col 4`, `col 5`
FROM table_name
INTO OUTFILE '/test.csv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

### OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"'

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I've done the query above to escape double quotes, but I want to escape both the backslash and double quotes characters in same query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape special characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql)

Comment: I think it would help your question to show us how you want the final data to look, highlighting double quotes/backslash where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it is due to enter character exists on any of your fields, not because of backslash. Try replacing enter character using REPLACE function, possibly you think that column has a enter character. Please find the sample query below.

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,REPLACE(COLUMNNAME , '\n', ' ') as COLUMNNAME,... 
INTO OUTFILE '/test.csv' 
CHARACTER SET utf8  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tableName
```

Hope it helps.