# Mysql escape ' and \

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I select a row in MySQL db where the value of a column contains `'` and `\` ?

For example, I want to select a column that matches this types of string:

> https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hirschsprung\'s-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20351556

What can I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: bit similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql

Comment: 1. By properly escaping or binding your values into your query, the same way it is always done. 2. Why does your value contain a backlash? "hirschsprung\'s-disease" is probably _not_ the desired phrase, no?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, both characters must be escaped into the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `urls` WHERE text LIKE "%\\\\\'%"
```