# MySQL - (#1242) Sub-query returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have tbl which include 2 columns: title and params, the values are like the following:

- title: 
  {"Teaching"}
- params:

{   "ufield926":"34",
    "ufield927":"Sud",
    "ufield928":"Ara",
    "ufield929":"Mecca",
    "ufield930":"1/1/1983",
    "ufield933":"011",
    "ufield934":"Mub",
    "ufield943":"SU/HI/14",
    "ufield944":"Average",
    "ufield946":"Female"
}
I want to extract the code after "ufield943": which is SU/HI/14 only and concatenate it with the value in title column to be like the following:

--> Teaching (SU/HI/14)

Here is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT CONCAT(title, "(", (select 
       substring(
         params,
         locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
         locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 21
       ) FROM tbl), ")") AS title
FROM tbl;
```

I get the following error everytime I run the query

> "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remove `{"..."}` from title with the [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) functions together.

I change `- 21` to `- 16` and add space before `(`

```
SELECT CONCAT(substring(title, 3,CHAR_LENGTH(title) - 4 ), " (", 
   substring(
     params,
     locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
     locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 16
   ), ")") AS Title
FROM tbl;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61f7a0/2)

Comment: It's working with single row, however when tried to run the query from "phpmyadmin" to apply the changes to all rows the mentioned error pops-up

Comment: The query works fine but get unintended results get "Teaching (SUV)" in all rows instead of "Teaching (SU/HI/14)" !!

Comment: Thank you it works. Another question in case I want to update title column to have the code I have grabbed form params to be like "Teaching (SU/HI/14)" with space and with only "/", what I could modify the mentioned query to get that?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a subquery if both the title and params field are in the same table

Comment: @AbbasSoliman For the space change `"("` to `" ("`. For change title that's not possible in pure SQL. You'll probably have to query the data out and then process it in whatever application is executing the query.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari thank you, i didn't see this big mistake. I change my response.

Comment: @Alberto Moro could I add "update"  with the working query to do so? if yes what could the query look like?

Comment: @AbbasSoliman You can try something like `UPDATE tbl SET title = CONCAT(...)`. For a more precise question I would like to know the structure of the table, some data you have and some data you want. Try doing something yourself then if you can't, you can open a new question

Comment: @Alberto Moro Thanks it works like charm, but wanted to replace "\/" to be "/" with the following query: "update tbl set title = replace(title,'\/','/')"  and get this answer: 
"0 rows affected" !!

Comment: @AbbasSoliman I try this and work fine [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAdntrK2Q5Gu1gbn8TUPFk/0). Take care when using `\\` beacuse is mysql special character. If you can help [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql)