# Formatting % in sql in python

Tags: mysql, sql

I have run into this issue before but for the life of me I cannot remember how I dealt with it. I have the following query I need to use:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(territory) NOT LIKE '%,%' THEN 'XXX' END
                  FROM myTable
                  WHERE i.id = %s AND territory_id=%s''', (self.pk, territory))
```

How do I escape the `'%,%'` in the sql query? Basically, I'm trying to find if the `group_concat` contains multiple elements.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Use `\` to escape `%`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/881208/2469308