# How to convert to string to insert in sql

Tags: javascript, formatting, string-formatting, backslash

I have this string:

```
x = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
```

But when I insert it gives problems with the quotes. 
How can I change the quotes to take the entire string?

I get the string from a query, I don't create it

Comment: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/escaping-literal-quotes-in-strings/

Comment: You need to escape the quotes. In your case, just replace the first and last double-quote with a single quote on each end. `x = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'`

Comment: thanks but I get the string from a query, I don't create it

Comment: What database server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Escape your doublequote for mysql.

```
x = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
```

Look at this answer. It may be helpful. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql)

You can also escape double quote using regex. Look

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
```

or

x = ""

```js
 x = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
 
 //or
 
  x = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES6, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

I also recommend using more descriptive variable names:

```
const xmlVersion = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You always want to use a parameterized query when creating SQL commands.  How you do that varies based upon which database server you are using and what language and components you use to connect to it.

**Injection attacks are the number 1 (according to the OWASP Top 10) vulnerability in web sites today.**