# Python Mysql Insert - tuple index out of range

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the snippet of code I am having problem with

```
for x in myresult:
    sql = "INSERT INTO `writing_correction` (`autoinc`, `q_usage_id`, `ruleId`, `message`, `replacements`, `offset`, `errorLength`, `category`, `ruleIssueType`) VALUES (NULL, %d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s )"
#    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
#    sql = "INSERT INTO `writing_correction` (`autoinc`, `q_usage_id`, `ruleId`, `message`, `replacements`, `offset`, `errorLength`, `category`, `ruleIssueType`) VALUES (NULL, '100', 'ruleid', 'message', 'replacemenet', '12', '3', 'cat', 'ruleissuetype')"
#    val = ("John", "Highway 21")
#    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    print(x[3])
    matches = tool.check(x[3])
    for y in matches:
#        sql = "INSERT INTO `writing_correction` (`autoinc`, `q_usage_id`, `ruleId`, `message`, `replacements`, `offset`, `errorLength`, `category`, `ruleIssueType`) VALUES (NULL, %d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %d, %s, %s )" % ( x[0], y.ruleId, y.message, y.replacements, y.offset , y.errorLength, y.category, y.ruleIssueType )
        val = ( [ x[0] ], (y.ruleId), (y.message), (y.replacements), [y.offset] , [y.errorLength] , (y.category), (y.ruleIssueType) )
        print(val)
#        mycursor.execute(sql , ( x[0], y.ruleId, y.message, y.replacements, y.offset , y.errorLength, y.category, y.ruleIssueType ) )
        mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
```

the commented code is my trial and error attempt to make it work but it is not working for some reason.

Currently I am getting following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 75, in __call__
    return bytes(self.params[index])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: No idea of SQL, but you can give it a try. Try replacing `mycursor.executemany(sql, val)` with `mycursor.executemany(sql % val)`

And in SQL statement also en-quote the format specifiers, for example `%d` &rarr; `"%d"`

Comment: @tbhaxor I made this change mycursor.executemany(sql % val) and now it is giving me another error which is TypeError: executemany() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seq_params'
 I am sorry I have no idea about Python Programming

Comment: use `execute` instead of `executemany`

Comment: now it says that I have error in sql syntax, Do i need to escape variables ? strings has quotes and rectangular brackets ( [] )

Comment: Yes you should, it is considered as a good approach, Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881194/how-do-i-escape-special-characters-in-mysql

Comment: I mean is that the error ?

Comment: Yes its an error

Answer (score 0):

`val` should be an array of tuples. With each tuple corresponding to a row. So fill out the array at a time, and then `executemany` once.

so:

```
val = []
for y in matches:
    val.append(  ( x[0], y.ruleId, y.message, y.replacements, y.offset , y.errorLength , y.category, y.ruleIssueType ) )

print(val)

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
```

ref: [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)

Comment: ok, While I understood your code and applied your suggestion it is still not working,

Comment: Do I need to Escape String ? It is giving me this error : AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'
also this, TypeError: Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: Is `mycursor` actually a [MySQLCursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html)? Are the values places in the tuple simple types (string or ints)? This isn't about escaping. Use the APs and not python string interpolation and you'll never need escaping. What is `tool.check`?

Comment: Yes it is indeed a MySQL Cursor, tool.check is from language-tool-python